# Elegant way to rearrange dictionary on number in key string

Tags: python, arrays

Say I have a dict with these objects:

```
< MultiValueDict: {
        u 'task-1-t_name': [u 'T2'],
        u 'task-INITIAL_FORMS': [u '0'],
        u 'task-1-end_date': [u '1010-01-01'],
        u 'task-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u '1000'],
        u 'order_wizard-current_step': [u 'task'],
        u 'task-TOTAL_FORMS': [u '2'],
        u 'task-1-start_date': [u '1010-01-01'],
        u 'task-0-t_name': [u 'T1'],
        u 'task-MIN_NUM_FORMS': [u '0'],
        u 'task-0-end_date': [u '1010-01-01'],
        u 'task-0-start_date': [u '1010-10-01']
```

What would be the most pythonic and elegant way to create an array or dictionary that would give me `task[0].start_time` or `task[n]['key_name']`

I feel like I am going to write a lot more code than necessary to do this

Comment: This question is assuming a lot of prior understanding ... What is a `MulitiValueDict`?  Is it from some framework?  If yes, adding a tag for that framework might help direct your question to the right people.  In your example code, what output are you expecting?

Comment: Try an show us what you've attempted so far instead of asking for generic advice. Also explaining what task[0] is and what start_time is would be helpful. What sort of final product do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the data for a Django formset. Rather than trying to manipulate it separately, you should use the methods available on the formset itself: once you have validated that formset, you can do `formset.forms[0].cleaned_data['start_time']` for example.